# Store result from sql statement into a string and compare it with the item selected in a listbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
{
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true");
   const string SQL = "SELECT EventName FROM Event)";//the result of this statement to be stored in a string
   if (li.Selected = //the string)//compare here
   {
      Response.Redirect("asd.aspx?name=" + a);//at here i want to use the compared value
   }
}
```

I want to store the details from the above SQL statement into a string and compare it with 
the item that is selected in the listbox. Upon comparison, if they are equal I want to  `response.redirect` the compared a label in another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to execute that SQL and get the result back:

```
const string SQL = "SELECT EventName FROM Event";   //the result of this statement to be stored in a string
List<string> eventNames = new List<string>();

// set up SQL connection and command
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PSeminar;Integrated Security=true;Trusted_Connection=Yes;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con))
{
    con.Open();

    // get a SqlDataReader to read multiple rows
    using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
       // while there are more result rows.....
       while(rdr.Read())
       {
           // grab the 0-index value from the result row
           eventNames.Add(rdr.GetString(0));
       }
    }

    con.Close();
}

foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
{
   // for each of the selected items in the ListBox - check if their .Text
   // is contained in the list of event names retrieved from the database table
   if (li.Selected && eventNames.Contains(li.Text))
   {
        Response.Redirect("asd.aspx?name=" + resultFromSQL);
   }
}
```

Also, since neither the connection nor the SQL you execute seem to be dependant on anything in the loop - don't unnecessarily do this SQL statement over and over again! Do it once before the loop and store the result...

Comment: What happens if there is more than one EventName in the Event table?

Comment: @Tim: good point - I added a `TOP 1` to get the first one. From the question, it's definitely not clear what should happen in this case...

Comment: I agree.  The OP has (IMO) a potential design flaw that he needs to address.  BTW, my comments are not a criticism of your answer, which is correct within the context of the information provided by the OP. :)

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the answer, i have tried the codes, but i have 3 errors at this line: if (string.Compare(li.Selected, resultFromSQL, true) == 0)-the error shows:Argument3:cannot convert from 'bool' to 'System.StringComaprison, Argument1:cannot convert from 'bool' to 'string' and the best overloaded method match for 'string.Compare(string, string ,system.stringcomparison)' has some invalid arguments. I would appreciate if you could help me out. Thanks once again.

Comment: @user917145: try using `li.Text` instead of `li.Selected`

Comment: @marc_s thanks it solves the issue. But upon executing the codes it shows the error incorrect syntax near at this line:resultFromSql = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); also upon reading the comments from tim i do have more then one eventname from the event table.Thanks for reminding the point tim. Is there anyway to solve this issue. Thanks once again for taking time to answer my questions. I am new to this language, so sorry for my ignorance. Thank you.

Comment: @user917145: updated my response; I now use a SqlDataReader to grab multiple `EventName` rows from your database table and store them in a `List<string>` - and then I check all selected items in the listbox to see if their `.Text` property is contained in that list of event names from the database

Comment: @marc_s i solved the issue regarding the error. There was an extra bracket at the sql command, i just had to remove it. But is there any ways to overcome if there is more then one eventname in the eventtable. Thanks once again. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @marc_s Thank you very much for helping me out.I tried the codes and they work perfect. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @tim thanks for reminding me the point if more than one eventname exists. It really was helpful. Thanks once again